# What's good practice for creating a key/value or dictionary for this type of use case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures, collections

I currently have a system that reports alerts and cuts tickets based on the alerts. Each alert must contain the name, resources, a link to the runbook, and documentation.

I am trying to write clean code for a use case.

**Problem**
The alert names are usually 35+ characters, and contain spaces.

Therefore the key/value pair will look something like this.

```
tickets = { 
    "Alert for Admin login": 
        f"Alert Name: {alert_name}",
        f"Runbook": {link},
        f"Documentation": {link},
        "Description": "Description here"
    }
```

This is just one alert for example. The system will receive multiple alerts so it may be around 10 key value pairs like this. The description will be the longest and may require spaces.

Would it be considered OK practice to implement it this way? I would like to may it as easy to read as possible. Any suggestions or guidance will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define a structure to describe each ticket, I suggest this one which is clean and easy to read while respecting the naming rules in python:

```
ticket = { 
    "name": f"{alert_name}",
    "description": "Description here",
    "runbook": f"{link}",
    "documentation": f"{link}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your data structured like in [@almamy-code](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18175554/almamy-code)'s answer you could then write a Dataclass for your alert. That lets you interact with them more readable.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


ticket = { 
    "name": f"Name here",
    "desc": "Description here",
    "runbook": f"link1",
    "docs": f"link2"
}


@dataclass
class Alert:
    name: str
    runbook: str
    docs: str
    desc: str

alert = Alert(*+ticket)
```

You could also inherit from your Alert to create Subclasses in order to differentiate and customize their behavior some more.

```py
class AdminAlert(Alert):
    pass
```

That makes the code in general more readable because the whole `alert["item"]` to set or get a value is replaced by a `alert.item`. Also you know what data it stores based on its type which helps decluttering things.

However you would also adapt the Dataclass, each time the alert structure changes, which happens not that often hopefully :)